# Ktor client connection refused on localhost

Tags: ktor

I have a server listening on `http://localhost:5173`.

When I request from that server in Ktor client, it errors with `Connection refused: no further information`.

```kotlin
val client = HttpClient(CIO)
val response: HttpResponse = client.get("http://localhost:5173")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ktor client seems to be rewriting `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` so getting the server to listen on `127.0.0.1` instead seems to fix it.